# How can you make autohotkey type automatically

Tags: automation, autohotkey

this is my current code

```
#SingleInstance Force

f5::
Click, 280, 1050 Left, 1
Sleep, 10000
Send, {'https://gangster.goodgamestudios.com/'}
Return

x::ExitApp
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you're trying to send the literal text `{'https://gangster.goodgamestudios.com/'}`, or if that was just some attempt of getting the correct syntax.

In any case, the problem here is that the `{ }` characters have a [special meaning](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#keynames) in a send command, so you're either going to need to escape them (`{{}` and `{}}`), or use a different send mode.

I'd recommend using the [Text mode](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#Text), along with [`SendInput`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#SendInputDetail):
`SendInput, {Text}{'https://gangster.goodgamestudios.com/'}`
(Assuming you wanted to send that literal text, if you just wanted to send just that link, it goes like this):

`SendInput, https://gangster.goodgamestudios.com/`
(No Text mode required here, because we aren't using any characters that have a special meaning)

Comment: Thanks for responding i figured it out by testing. But another problem i have is that i create a file that works perfectly, and the net time i start it it doesnt. Is autohotkey just very unreliable, or do you think it has to do with my code?

Comment: I really don't know what you tried to just say, sorry. But you probably did something wrong. Maybe try submitting a new question here if you can clearly explain your problem. And be sure to include your code as well.

Comment: this is my code the problem i have is that the mouseX and Y werent reliable i made a working version but when i tried it later it didnt work this is the code

Comment: this is my code the problem i have is that the mouseX and Y werent reliable i made a working version but when i tried it later it didnt work this is the code #SingleInstance Force

f5::
Click, 280, 1050 Left, 1
Sleep, 10000
Send, https://gangster.goodgamestudios.com
Sleep, 1000
Click, 280, 160 Left, 1
Sleep, 5000
Click, 1000, 580 Left, 1
Sleep, 5000
Click, 280, 215 Left, 1
Sleep, 15000
Click, 800, 980 Left, 1
Sleep, 3000
Click, 1200, 850 Left, 1
Sleep, 2000

Comment: Click, 1200, 850 Left, 1
Sleep, 2000
Click, 900, 1000 Left, 1
Sleep, 4000
Click, 900, 650 Left, 2
Send, Paco1
Sleep, 1000
Click, 1000, 650 Left, 1
Return

x::ExitApp